# How can ı convert a jpg file to a svg code?

Tags: figma

Converting a jpg file to a svg code.
Hi guys, my friend sent me a jpeg file and I want to add this file to Figma but when ı try to change the structure of file in Figma, ı could not alter the colors and other things. If ı get an svg code and paste it to figma, ı may solve the problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. JPEG is a raster image type (saves info about pixels) and SVG is vector (saves lines and fills mathematically according to degrees, thickness, etc)